# django store incremental numeric values in a table?

Tags: django, model, integer, increment

I want to make a rank application, that will calculate the rank of each course uploaded on a platform.

Is it a good approach to have stored in a table values like number of downloads, and number of views, like that?

```
class Courserate(models.Model):
     course = models.ForeignKey(Courses)
     downloads = models.IntegerField(editable = False, default = 0)
     views = models.IntegerField(editable = False, default = 0)
     positive_votes = models.IntegerField(editable = False, default = 0)
     negative_votes = models.IntegerField(editable = False, default = 0)
```

also, when I'm trying to take the number of downloads, for example, for a course belonging to a specific classroom, how should I do it? I mean, a query like:

```
courses = Courses.objects.filter(classroom = userclass)
downloads = Courserate.objects.filter(course = courses).downloads
```

the downloads query doesn't work, how can I 'take' the number of downloads for each course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fine to save the numbers as you do.
To make the query return a single object (filter always returns a queryset) you have to use `get` and not `filter`:

```
downloads = Courserate.objects.get(course = course).downloads
```

This should work if only one object matches your query, if there are more matches it will throw an exception! If you are using `filter` you have to iterate over the returned queryset to access `downloads`:

```
courses = Courserate.objects.filter(course = course)
for course in courses:
    print course.downloads # do something with downloads here
```

If you want to get more than one course and filter your `CourseRate` objects for a list of `Courses` use `__in`:

```
courses = Courserate.objects.filter(course__in = courses)
```